# HD mobiles displays my web site contents too small how to fix it?

Tags: android, css

I have created a responsive website (same css and javascript for all devices). Here is the link.
www.focusapparels.in/tfact/index.php.
It works well in pcs and ordinary mobile phone.
The problem is, when we load it in HD mobiles like Samsun Note 3 (resolution 1080 x 1920 pixels) all the contents displays as too small. Please someone tell me what to do.

Comment: You might have read it already but [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on android dev says: _To optimize your application's UI for the different screen sizes and densities, you can provide alternative resources for any of the generalized sizes and densities. Typically, you should provide alternative layouts for some of the different screen sizes and alternative bitmap images for different screen densities. At runtime, the system uses the appropriate resources for your application, based on the generalized size or density of the current device screen._

Comment: @Nikhil, that's for native apps. The question refers to CSS.  Tom, what CSS framework are you using (if any?)

Comment: Have you tried adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to your webpage

Comment: I am not using any CSS framework.

Comment: @Phix: My bad, apologies.

Comment: @Tom: If you're not doing so, I suggest you should use higher res images while scaling them down on smaller devices, otherwise there's no way images would look good on large screens.